# Is it correct to mix exception handling with boolean logic?

Tags: python, error-handling

I have code which can either raise an exception or return a `True`or a `False`. I would like to run the same code

- either when the exception is raised
- or when the function returns a `True`

I tried to put the condition in the `except` clause and it works:

```
def fun(s1, s2):
    if s1:
        raise IndexError
    else:
        return s2

try:
    a = fun(True, True)
except IndexError or a:
    print("error")
```

I have not seen such construction in the documentation - is it correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need to distinguish between `fun` returning true and it raising an index error, you can raise an IndexError yourself.

```
try:
    if fun(True, True):
        raise IndexError
except IndexError:
    print("error")
```

Comment: Ah, this is a very interesting solution. I can even distinguish the cases by rasing a specific `ValueError`

Answer (score 4):

It's syntactically valid, in the same way that "Colorless green ideas sleep furiously." is syntactically valid English, but it's completely meaningless and doesn't do what you want.

```
IndexError or a
```

will evaluate to `IndexError`, so the `except` only triggers on IndexErrors. There is no syntactical support to make an `except` trigger on arbitrary boolean conditions.

If you want to do a thing when the function either returns True or raises an exception, you can set a "do the thing" flag in both cases and then check the flag:

```
try:
    do_the_thing = fun(True, True)
except IndexError:
    do_the_thing = True
if do_the_thing:
    do_it()
```

Comment: *There is no syntactical support to make an except trigger on arbitrary boolean conditions.* -- this is what I was wondering, actually. The solution you proposed is where I am coming from, and was looking for a more compact way to do it. Thanks.